# Is there a way to create an ActionLink with HTML 5 Data- attributes?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html

HTML5 allows the use of custom attributes prefixed with the phrase "data-" which pass validation without the use of a custom DTD ([more info](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/)).  In Asp.Net MVC, is there any way to specify an ActionLink with a data- attribute?

The typical method for adding attributes to an ActionLink is to pass in an anonymous object, with a custom property for each object:

```
new { customattribute="value" }
```

What I'd like to do is:

```
new { data-customattribute="value" }
```

But this doesn't work, because the hyphen character isn't valid in property names.  Is there any way around this restriction?  Or do I just have to choose between using ActionLinks and using data- attributes?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

or you can use

`new { data_customattribute="value" }`

and the compiler is smart enough to know what you mean

Comment: yes to achieve the same solution in version prior to mvc3 you should use @çağdaş solution

Answer (score 22):

Yes, there is an overload for `ActionLink` method which takes an `IDictionary<string,object>` instead of an anonymous object.

```
<%=Html.ActionLink("text", "Index", "Home", null /*routeValues*/, 
    new Dictionary<string, object> { 
       { "data-customattribute", "value" }, 
       { "data-another", "another-value" } 
    })%>
```

Outputs :

```
<a data-another="another-value" data-customattribute="value" href="/">text</a>
```

Comment: Perfect. Note to future readers: If you use an IDictionary for the HTML attributes, you must also use a RouteDictionary for the routeValues parameter (you can use the same syntax as the HTML attributes use above).