# How can you specify a css class name on ActionLinks in Razor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

The following code generates an error:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Title", "action", new { id=1 }, new { @class = "myCssClass" });
```

I tried to use @ since `class` is a keyword. How should I write it when using razor?

**Edit**

The problem was not really the at sign, but that I didn't use blocks together with my `if`:

```
@if (blabla)
    @Html.ActionLink("Title", "action", new { id=1 }, new { @class = "myCssClass" });
```

Works:

```
@if (blabla)
{
    @Html.ActionLink("Title", "action", new { id=1 }, new { @class = "myCssClass" });
}
```

Up voted both answers since they made me realize the problem.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Try to write something like:

```
@(Html.ActionLink("Title", "action", new { id=1 }, new { @class = "myCssClass" }));
```

There is a good post about Razor related to your problem:
[ScottGu Blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/16/asp-net-mvc-3-implicit-and-explicit-code-nuggets-with-razor.aspx)

Comment: How do you add a value to the 'data-something' attribute?

Comment: @(Html.ActionLink("Title", "action", new { id=1 }, new { @class = "myCssClass", data-something="something data" }));

Comment: Thanks for the reply but that won't work because of the hyphen, I did find a solution here though...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2339096/is-there-a-way-to-create-an-actionlink-with-html-5-data-attributes

Comment: It's possible to this way also:

@Html.ActionLink("Title", "action", null, new { @class = "someClass" })

Answer (score 8):

Simply:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Title", "action", new { id=1 }, new { @class = "myCssClass" })
```

will work in ASP.NET MVC 3 RC2. Razor is intelligent.

Comment: @jgauffin, I've just run this with RC2 and it worked fine :-) Are you sure you are testing this with RC2?

Comment: I'm confused - this is the same as the code in his question? That being said - the code in your question *should* work. I suggest you are possibly using the wrong `ActionLink` overload - i've had problems with this in the past. What error are you getting?

Comment: @RPM1984, yes it is the same as the question. In my answer I highlight that this works in ASP.NET MVC 3 RC2. I've tested it.