# ASP.NET Core 5 error: "class" is a reserved word and cannot be used in implicit expressions

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-5

I am migrating an old application from ASP.NET MVC 5 (`System.Web.Mvc` v5.2.7.0) to ASP.NET Core 5.

In ASP.NET MVC 5.* this code was valid:

```
@{ var htmlAttributes = new {@class="x"}; }
```

I used this approach to set html attributes dynamically but now I am getting this error:

> RZ1007 "class" is a reserved word and cannot be used in implicit expressions

It looks like `@{}` syntax is no longer valid to insert script blocks within a razor page.

If I do

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name, new { @class = "bold" } )
```

it works.

Any idea how to overcome this limitation?

**Note:** This question is about .Net5 razor, not Asp.Net MVC 5. The scenario is different to the one described in [How can you specify a css class name on ActionLinks in Razor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4469354/how-can-you-specify-a-css-class-name-on-actionlinks-in-razor)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can you specify a css class name on ActionLinks in Razor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4469354/how-can-you-specify-a-css-class-name-on-actionlinks-in-razor)

Comment: @FranzGleichmann no, unfortunately my scenario is slightly different. I need to dynamically create html attributes object, while the quoted question asks how to do it statically, Also, this question is about .Net5 Razor and the question is about Asp.Net MVC.

Comment: okay. but: i just found [this](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/15004) - which contains the solution of using `@@class`, and the info that this is a low-priority bug that probably won't be fixed. hope that info helps you

Comment: this is not a bug it's by design, when you write `@class` it means you declaring a C# class inside your CSHTML the `class` is a reserved word/keyword in C#, and when you use `@@class` it means you are writing the word `class` as a string.

Answer (score 1):

As [Franz Gleichmann](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67647688/asp-net-core-5-error-class-is-a-reserved-word-and-cannot-be-used-in-implicit#comment-119571098) pointed out in the comments above, you have to use double `@@`:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name, new { @@class = "bold" } )
```