# How to use Url Helper in splited js/coffee files

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, coffeescript

When I write javascript code in ASP.NET MVC views, I can use @Url.Content() to generate a reference path.

Recently, I'm play with coffeescript and use [MINDSCAPE Web WorkBench](http://www.mindscapehq.com/products/web-workbench) to generate js files in Visual Studio.

However, when I split all my js file to multiple files, I can't use Url helpers so that I must hard code url path like '/Dashboard/User/12' into coffee files.

Is there any work around that I can use url helpers in splited js/coffee files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use html5 `data-*` attributes on html elements and from your js file you can access them

**Html**

```
<li class='elem' data-url='example.com'>something</li>
```

**Javascript**

```
$('.elem').data('url') // return example.com
```

and that is the idea of unobtrusive Javascript ,put the needed information in the html document without putting Javascript code in it

---

if your using html helpers and want to use `data-*` [check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2339096/is-there-a-way-to-create-an-actionlink-with-html-5-data-attributes/5068110#5068110)

Comment: It's a good work around. I'am afraid if some infomation leaks out there.

Comment: its not a work around , its the way to communicate , between js and html , before `data-*` there were 2 solutions , putting javascript in html which is bad practice , or making the element id or class name mean something then process them with js ,which is also not good

Comment: i don't understand about the leakage scenario, you don't have to be concerned with leakage when writing info needed for Javascript to process , you have to be concerned in the authentication process